# Can verigy test methods' params, aliases and methods' be defined at different times?

Tags: origen-sdk

I am importing all of my [Verigy 93k test methods](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Custom_Test_Methods)' parameters based on an ASCII file I received from Verigy.  At the time of import, the test method attribute aliases and methods won't be known.  Can they be created statically at a later time, by various developers?  The code below is just a snippet of the test method param hash I am trying to auto-create.

thx

```
add_tml :my93k,
    class_name:      'my93k',
    Functional: {
      class_name:   'Functional',
      'ErrorMap.DutCyclesPerTesterCycles' => [:string,  '1'],
      'ErrorMap.EdgesPerTesterCycle' => [:string,  '4'],
      'ErrorMap.Location' => [:string,  'RAM'],
      # Attribute aliases can be defined like this:
      aliases: {
      },
      # Define any methods you want the test method to have
      methods: {
      }
    },

    my_other_test: {
      # Define another test in exactly the same way...
    }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that today, but I don't think it would be hard to add that capability if you want.

From your example above, `test_methods.my93k.Functional` will return an instance of `OrigenTesters::SmartestBasedTester::Base::TestMethod`, which is defined here: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/5b89bf287b3d307bd6708c878666f3609a5fd3af/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/test_method.rb

The contents of the hash assigned to `:Functional` above are passed in as the initialization options when the `TestMethod` instance is instantiated.
If you look at the implementation of the `initialize` method, you will see where it defines the aliases and methods.

You could expose that same functionality via some new methods to provide an API for developers to add additional aliases and methods later in the process. e.g. `test_methods.my93k.Functional.add_alias(:blah)`.

Comment: OK thanks for the explanation.  Seems like some more PRs will be on the way.